Picked up item goes through walls
I made the lifting and carrying of an object by assigning it the position of a cube, which always moves in front of the game character in 3D. Picking, carrying and throwing work correctly, but the following situation occurs:
this.gameObject.transform.position = pos.position;
A lifted object ignores everything that does not have a Rigidbody, and for those that do, it ignores the weight of the object (thereby you can move even the heaviest ones). I understand that this is because I'm setting the item's position "forcibly" rather than using physics, but my attempts to implement this through AddForce or other Rigidbody methods have not been successful. Now it works like this:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Take : MonoBehaviour
{
    float distance = 2;
    public Transform pos;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private FPC_Param fpc_;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb =  GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        fpc_ =  GameObject.Find("RigidbodyPlayer").GetComponent<FPC_Param>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, distance) && fpc_.Take==false)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            fpc_.Take = true;
            rb.MovePosition(pos.position);
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rb.isKinematic == true)
        {
            this.gameObject.transform.position = pos.position;
            this.gameObject.transform.rotation = pos.rotation;

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G))
            {
                fpc_.Take = false;
                rb.useGravity = true;
                rb.isKinematic = false;
                rb.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 500);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {
                fpc_.Take = false;
                rb.useGravity = true;
                rb.isKinematic = false;
                rb.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

Here's a short video of how an object interacts with other objects with a Rigidbody, and how it interacts with walls (without a Rigidbody):
https://youtu.be/boNFzV2QvHo

A kinematic rigidbody, by definition, does not collide with static colliders (your walls). Keep it as a dynamic rigidbody, and instead of setting the transform.position, set use MovePosition like you did with your raycast. This does mean you'll have to change your "isKinematic" check to something else.

This is a really difficult problem to fix and there isn't a one-size fits all answer. many games solve this in different ways. if you want physics like behaviour then youll have to keep the item in the physics simulation and move it with forces (like @ipodtouch0218 says) but it may be perfectly valid for you to not have held items interact physically. In that case you want to change the render layer of held items so they always render on-top, therefore remaining visible even when clipping. A third option is just make the player drop the item when it crashes into stuff. I’ve seen games do all 3

If you don't want to solve the physics by hand then you could use a Unity Spring Joint.

Thank you all! I'll try your options soon. Unfortunately, there is no time to check now. I'll be sure to write here when I try it
